# TCL: How to search for a specific variable name going back in frames from current execution point, then retrieve its value?

Tags: tcl, frame, info

I have some code that's executed from within a proc but one level up.

e.g.

```
proc foo {} {
  set <unique_var_name> <some value>
  uplevel 1 {<script>}
}
```

`<script>` can be any code and may contain multiple proc calls.

I want to write another proc 'get_`<unique_var_name>`' which can be called from anywhere within `<script>` and return whatever `<unique_var_name>` is set to in foo i.e. `<some_value>`

I assume I need to go back one frame at a time and then somehow test for the existence of `<unique_var_name>`, but how can this be done?

Comment: just to clarify, by `<unique_var_name>` i mean I can guarantee a variable of the same name will not be defined within <script>

Answer (score 0):

In Tcl, you cannot step down into a "lower" stack frame, or bind variables that way (sth. to mimic languages having lexical scoping). `uplevel` is a one-way, i.e., up-way operation.

```
proc foo {} {
    set XXX 1
    uplevel 1 {
      puts [get_XXX]
    }
}

proc get_XXX {} {
    uplevel 1 set XXX
}

foo
```

Here, `uplevel 1` in `get_XXX` will point to the caller frame of `get_XXX`, which is the caller frame of `foo` (and NOT `foo` itself as caller).

### A possible alternative

```
set XXX 2

proc foo {} {
    uplevel 1 {apply {{XXX} {
        upvar 1 XXX globalXXX
        puts $globalXXX
        puts [get_XXX]
    }} 1}
}

proc get_XXX {} {
    uplevel 1 set XXX
}

foo
```

Using a Tcl lambda (`apply`), you can create an dedicated execution context which can access both the shared calling level (`globalXXX`) and a "local" `XXX`.

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer

Comment: I agree, how would I post a comment with a formatted code example?

Comment: You can't. Asking for clarification doesn't need a code example, just questions.

Comment: in your modified example XXX is not being set locally within proc foo, but this is where it needs to reside. I cannot create the variable XXX using uplevel 1 as it can no longer be guaranteed to be unique and may conflict with an existing variable at that level. this is why i need a proc specifically to retrieve the value from within foo

Comment: @CarlMarkham I disagree, showing a tentative code example facilitates problem understanding, rather than lengthy Q&A via comments. I will remove this answer once the OP has provided some clarification, or an affirmative answer has been provided.

Answer (score 0):

When you `uplevel` (to a level other than your own), the code you run inside there can't access the local variables of the command that does the `uplevel`. There's no `uplevel -1` or `upvar -1`. This is because you can trivially call code which does another `uplevel`, and there's no way of describing which branch of the tree to go down:

```
originalCall
     |______________
     |     |        |
    foo   get   something
```

If you've got some state token (e.g., a variable name that is unguessable), you'll have to explicitly tell that to the script that `foo` uses `uplevel` to run. You can do that by appending it as list element (only really useful for the “command prefix” style of script), substituting it in before running, or by setting a variable of the caller to the value. This third case is one of the main uses for `upvar`, and works very well in API terms if the caller gets to nominate the variable to write:

```
proc foo {varName} {
  upvar 1 $varName var
  # You can keep your own private copy as well; that's trivial
  set var <someValue>
  uplevel 1 {<script>}
}
```

Of course, it means that the caller has to manage the uniqueness and so on… but that tends to be really easy in practice.